cursor no longer showing matching bracket in Eclipse
What used to work when I was doing java in eclipse is if I put the curser on a closing bracket a  line (or help) would pop up showing the line that opened this bracket.  That no longer seems to work.  I can do a CTRL-Shift-P but that is more work and actually jumps to the opening bracket instead of just showing me the code.  I came across
https://coderanch.com/t/104853/ide/find-brackets-match-eclipse#:~:text=The%20second%20way%20is%20to,Bracket%20from%20the%20menu%20bar.
I noticed I already had matching bracket selected. I figure somehow I must have unset some other setting but am not sure what that setting is.  The google search showed the above.
Another theory I have which it might be is I am now using Version: 2024-03 (4.31.0)
Build id: 20240307-1437.  I notice with this new Eclipse you can now only refresh at the project level and not at any directory level.  I wonder if a change has also been made for putting the cursor next to a closing brace?  Or do I somehow have a setting not set?

The thing you came across has been posted 18 years ago. I can't reproduce what you say. How can your issue be reproduced in the current Eclipse version 2024-09? Make sure to provide a minimal reproducible example as text. If it is reproducible in Eclipse 2024-09, is it also reproducible in a fresh installation of Eclipse 2024-09 without additional plugins and a fresh workspace?

It is also unclear to me about what popup you are talking. Do you mean something like sticky scrolling which was introduced in Eclipse 2024-09, and for which a plugin existed in the past that did something similar via a popup.
